# Why does Azure AD joined account name on local computer not sync after change of UPN in Azure AD?

Tags: windows, entra-id, user-accounts, synchronization, rename

A user asked me to change his account name in Azure AD, which I did (actually did it through GoDaddy UI but end result is change of user principal name). The account name has changed on his Teams and email (after signing out and signing back in) but has not changed on his local computer, even after several days. Below is a screenshot from Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts\Manage Accounts, showing his old username. His account is Azure AD joined. Is there any way to get it to sync with Azure AD? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Account will only change if you have set up write-back, within an AD environment. Local Account details cannot be managed via Azure, must be done on machine through relevant account options, or create a new local account

Comment: I see, thanks, I will maybe disconnect his AAD joined account (which should delete it) and at the same time create a new local account and connect it to AAD.